# Internet explorer css: Joomla Custom template

Tags: css, internet-explorer, joomla

I am trying to add an internet explorer only css file called ie.css.

I have built a simple custom joomla template, it is working fine in every browser except....usual culprit IE!

I have added ie.css to the css folder and i am struggling to get the file to only be read from IE. 
This is my .php file:

```html
<?php

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/main.css');
  $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/header.css');
  $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/footer.css');
  $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/container.css');
 $stylelink = '<!--[if lte IE 9]>' ."\n";
$stylelink .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie.css" />' ."\n";
$stylelink .= '<![endif]-->' ."\n";
 
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag($stylelink);
$doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/java/java.js', 'text/javascript');


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<jdoc:include type="head" />

<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<div id="back">

<jdoc:include type="modules" name="background_image" style="none" /></div>
<div class="wrapper">
      <div id="logo"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo" style="none" /></div>
      
    <div class="menu">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav-main" style="none" />
      
        
   </div>
   
   <div class="container">
   <jdoc:include type="component" />
       <div id="home_content_top">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content_area_one" style="none" />
        </div>
       
        <div id="home_discount">
         <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content_area_two" style="none" />
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="none" />
       
      
      </div>
   </div>
       



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined the base path when trying to call your CSS file, so currently it's trying to find:

```
www.example.com/css/ie.css
```

when the actual path is:

```
www.example.com/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/css/ie.css
```

Also, I would not use PHP to render conditional statements. It's much cleaner to do it without, so remove all of this:

```
$stylelink = '<!--[if lte IE 9]>' ."\n";
$stylelink .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie.css" />' ."\n";
$stylelink .= '<![endif]-->' ."\n";
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag($stylelink);
```

Add add the following inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Just a side note too. You do not need to call `JFactory::getDocument()` twice, only once, like you have at the top of your code.